# how to run more than one test from command line using nunit console runner?

Tags: jenkins, nunit

I have list of failed tests (belongs to different classes, namespaces), when I try to run from Jenkins or local command line with below syntax seeing

**.\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe --where test==failedTest1,failedTest2,failedTest3 .\ABCTesting\bin\Debug\Api.IntegrationTesting.dll**

**output**
Run Settings
DisposeRunners: True
WorkDirectory: C:\API_IntegrationTesting
ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2
ImageRequiresX86: False
ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False
NumberOfTestWorkers: 12

Test Run Summary
Overall result: Passed
Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
Start time: 2021-06-10 20:43:49Z
End time: 2021-06-10 20:43:52Z
Duration: 2.574 seconds

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic problems in the syntax of your `where` clause...

1. The comma (',') has no function in a `where` clause. Consequently, you are telling NUnit to look for a test named "failedTest1,failedTest2,failedTest3". Most likely `<g>` you don't have a test by that name.
2. The `test` operand is specified as the `FullName` of the test, i.e. the namespace and actual test name.

So the correct syntax in your example could be...

```
--where "test==My.Namespace.failedTest1 || test==My.Namespace.failedTest2 || test==My.Namespace.failedTest3"
```

As an alternative approach, you may want to consider using the `--testlist` option, which allows you to place the test names in a text file, one full name per line.